# How can I configure the 'staticcheck' linter in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: go, go-staticcheck

I installed staticcheck, but it doesn't tell me any problems in my Visual Studio Code.

I configured my linter to use staticcheck and I looked everywhere on the Internet. It still doesn't work.

Here is a part of my *settings.json* file:

```json
{
  "go.formatTool": "goimports",
  "go.useLanguageServer": true,
  "go.lintTool": "staticcheck",
  "go.lintFlags": [],
  "go.testFlags": ["-v"],
  "go.toolsManagement.autoUpdate": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": { "source.fixAll.eslint": true }
}
```

I already tried to add `"-check=all"` on the `go.lintFlags`. I reloaded my Visual Studio Code, but it still doesn't work.

When I checked the official website they talk about `staticcheck.conf`, but I don't get it since there are multiple files named `staticcheck.conf` on my system.

Comment: what the output  of `which staticheck`? canyou also enable debug of `vscode-go` (https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#collect-gopls-information)?

Comment: `which staticcheck` give me : 
`/home/<me>/go/bin/staticcheck`
I tried to enable debug same results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `"go.lintTool": "staticcheck",` because, this is (`staticcheck`) default linting tool in `vscode-go`.

If you have language serve enabled, you need to turn `staticcheck` [explicitly](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/c5ebe02a9d69bbabf26311c74cac1eb19ae0559b/docs/advanced.md) with

```
"gopls": { "ui.diagnostic.staticcheck": true }.
```

As alternative, you can set up `golangci-lint` as your linter and turn `staticcheck` in it.

Comment: I deleted : 
`"go.lintTool": "staticcheck"` since I added it manually to resolve the problem.
I tried the to add the : `"gopls": { "ui.diagnostic.staticcheck": true }`
Same situation sadly

Comment: Oh I think your solution worked, but I have to go to the specific files where the problem is. 
If I am in another file where there is no problem, it says no problems have been detected in the workspace.
Is there anyway to have all the problems in the workspace listed?

Comment: I have the expected situation for the check `ST1000` when I add this on my settings.json:
` "gopls": { 
    "ui.diagnostic.staticcheck": true,
    "ui.semanticTokens": true,
    "ui.diagnostic.analyses": {
      "ST1000": true,
    },
  },`
But I want all checks.

Comment: Isn’t staticcheck supports regents?

Comment: Didn't tried to contact them yet

Comment: Sorry (phone autocomplete fail). Regexps… try “*”:true

Comment: According Hanna, there is no way to configure linter via gopls. Try golangci-lint option.

Comment: I found that even though I had `staticcheck` set as the default linter, `staticcheck` was somehow not installed. I clicked on a different linter, then back on `staticcheck` which prompted me to install it. Once installed, the linter worked as expected.